# Visual studio code throwing errors inside the smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, smart-contract-wallets

I tested a smart contract on remix and I wanted to test it with a hardhat, so copied it in my code editor but I got a bunch of errors and yellow lines under the code inside the smart contract.

How can I fix that, please?

These are the errors that visual studio is throwing
[image]

Comment: is your file extension `.sol`? + install `solidity` plugin on your vscode

Comment: Yes, the solidity plugin is installed and the file extension with .sol

Comment: Ok then share the whole file

Comment: I updated the Image. Thanks Adam

Comment: Can you remove and re-install solidity plugin?